# Printed value in IDE and exported values are different

Tags: python, python-2.7

The values that I get from printing in the console and saving to file are different. When I print in the console, I get 1's and 0's in subsequent lines depending on whether `getchromosome()` is true or not.

However, when I try to get it to print this output to an excel sheet, I get 500 0's each in their own cell within a row. The 500 limit appears to be due to the `for i in xrange(500)` line, but I don't know what to replace it with.

Questions :

1. What should I replace the `for i in xrange(500)` line with to allow the program to put as much data into the spreadsheet as it is given?
2. Why is this code printing only 0's in the spreadsheet, but both 1's and 0's depending on whether `getchromosome()` is true or not in the console?

Many thanks

Edit:
spreadsheet structure

> CHR    Position    Ref Mutation
>
> chr22  44357025    C   G
>
> chr22  44357025    C   G
>
> chr22  44381361    G   A

The position number from the spreadsheet is used to find a character within the human chromosome file, in this case chr22, which has been loaded in as seq. This file is lines full of the characters A,C,T and G. If the conditions in getchromosome() are met, I want a 1 to be printed in the file, and a 0 to be printed if they aren't (on separate lines of course, the data set for this chromosome is around 1500)

```
import xlwt
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def getlocation():    
    CHR = 'chr22'
    rownum = 1
    cellrefA = "A%s" %rownum
    cellrefB = "B%s" %rownum
    cellrefD = "D%s" %rownum
    while CHR == 'chr22':
        rownum = rownum + 1
        cellrefA = "A%s" %rownum
        cellrefB = "B%s" %rownum
        cellrefD = "D%s" %rownum
        if sheet [cellrefA].value == "chr22" :
            x = sheet[cellrefB].value
            D = sheet[cellrefD].value     
            CpGval=getchromosome(x,D)
        
            print CpGval

            if CHR == "chr22":
                f = open('out.xls', 'w')
                for i in xrange(500):
                    f.write("%s\n" %CpGval) 

        if rownum == 108172:
           CHR = 'stop'

def getchromosome(x,D):
    CpGnum = 0
    dnastring1 = seq[x-1]
    dnastring2 = seq[x]
    dnastring3 = seq[x+1]
    
    if dnastring2 == "C" and D != "C":
        if dnastring3 == "G": 
            CpGnum += 1
    if dnastring2 == "G" and D != "G":
        if dnastring1 == "C":
            CpGnum += 1    

    return CpGnum

print getlocation()
```

Comment: Edit the question to show what your spreadsheet looks like, i.e. some sample data and what your expected output should be for that data. As you have it, you are writing the single number returned by `getchromosome()` to the file 500 times. If you removed the `for` it would at least match what you see on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've edited the question now. What do you mean by removing the for? when I remove the line I only get one 0 in the spreadsheet. If I understand what you are saying, the result for the first piece of data is being printed multiple times. What I don't understand is how this is even possible? The data is being passed from getchromosome() to getlocation() otherwise the correct results wouldn't be printed in the console

Comment: You should move `f = open('out.xls', 'w')` to above the `while`.